# Given matrix $B =\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, find $e^{Bt}$ from a short infinite series

Tags: linear-algebra

Given matrix $B =\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, find $e^{Bt}$ from a short infinite series. Also check that the derivative of $e^{Bt}$ is $Be^{Bt}$

I found that the eigenvalues of $B$ are $\lambda_{1} = \lambda_{2} = 0$, and its eigenvalues ore $s_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}, s_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$, respectively.

Now I don't really understand what the problem means by finding $e^{Bt}$ from a **short infinite series**, normally I would've found $e^{Bt}$ like this:

$e^{Bt} = Se^{\Lambda t}S^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: It is short because $B^k=0$ when $k< \infty$.

Comment: Also, $S^{-1}$ does not exist for your $S$ as $S$ has rank one. This $B$ is a Jordan block essentially, it is not diagonalizable, you can't do it with eigenvectors... I think you're just supposed to directly calculate from $e^A = I+A+\frac{1}{2}A^2+ \cdots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to worry about eigenvalues and eigenvectors for this one, but you do need to note that

$B^2 = 0, \tag{1}$

which makes the exponential series $\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(Bt)^n$ pretty short:

$e^{Bt} = I + Bt, \tag{2}$

and that's it, since $B^n = 0$ for $n \ge 2$.  From (2), the derivative of $e^{Bt}$ is

$(e^{Bt})' = B; \tag{3}$

Now note that

$Be^{Bt} = B(I + Bt) = B + B^2t = B = (e^{Bt})' \tag{4}$

by (1), (2) and (3).

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***